The specified instance type r8g.medium is not valid
When trying to deploy elastic beanstalk instance type r8g.medium in us-east-2, get error

Updating Auto Scaling launch configuration named: awseb-e-sh8msjpgjp-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingLaunchConfiguration-rk4dt1gQ09xZ failed Reason: Resource handler returned message: "The specified instance type r8g.medium is not valid (Service: AutoScaling, Status Code: 400

Works fine with r7g.medium, and docs say r8g should be available in this region. I've made sure I'm using the correct availability zone.

same error as https://github.com/aws/elastic-beanstalk-roadmap/issues/309

What region are you launching it in? Have you tried the same deployment in us-east-1 where I guess all instance types are available?
